# Copying std::string in a for loop is much slower in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, performance, vectorization

A benchmark is available: https://quick-bench.com/q/oJSjBcuR6A4twOChX_PdoX5vhyU

Why copying std::string in a for loop (using operator[]) is much slower than assign copy operator, and slower than either std::u8string or char* doing the same thing?

Does it have something to do with strict pointer aliasing? How can I hint the compiler to avoid this penalty?

These two are super slow:

```cpp
static void str_loop(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::string   a(N,'a'), b(N,'b'); 
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) a[i]=b[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(str_loop);

static void str_loop_data(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::string   a(N,'a'), b(N,'b'); 
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) a.data()[i]=b.data()[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(str_loop_data);
```

And the rest are roughly equally much faster:

```cpp
static void str_assign(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::string   a(N,'a'), b(N,'b'); 
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    a=b;
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(str_assign);

static void u8str_assign(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::u8string c(N,'c'), d(N,'d');
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    c=d;
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(c);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(d);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(u8str_assign);

 
static void str_loop_ptr(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::string   a(N,'a'), b(N,'b'); 
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    char *dst = a.data();
    char *src = b.data();
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) dst[i]=src[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(str_loop_ptr);

 
static void u8str_loop_ptr(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::u8string c(N,'c'), d(N,'d');
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    auto *dst = c.data();
    auto *src = d.data();
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) dst[i]=src[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(c);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(d);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(u8str_loop_ptr);

 
static void vec_loop(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::vector<char> e(N,'e'),f(N,'f');
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) e[i]=f[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(e);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(f);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(vec_loop);



static void u8str_loop(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::u8string c(N,'c'), d(N,'d');
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) c[i]=d[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(c);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(d);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(u8str_loop);

static void vec_loop_data(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::vector<char> e(N,'e'),f(N,'f');
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) e.data()[i]=f.data()[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(e);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(f);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(vec_loop_data);



static void u8str_loop_data(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::u8string c(N,'c'), d(N,'d');
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) c.data()[i]=d.data()[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(c);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(d);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(u8str_loop_data);

 
static void str_memcpy(benchmark::State& state) {
  std::string   a(N,'a'), b(N,'b'); 
  // Code before the loop is not measured 
  for (auto _ : state) {
    memcpy(a.data(),b.data(),N*sizeof(a[0]));
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
}
BENCHMARK(str_memcpy);
```

[image: Bench screenshot]

Comment: Please try to make your questions *self contained*. Any code need to be present in the question itself.

Comment: And if you're wondering about array element by element copying, then most copying functions in the standard library are highly optimized, for example by copying multiple elements at once.

Comment: You can check the [source code](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00771_source.html) yourself to find how they have implemented those operations.

Comment: I'm not sure what's prolem with it.. neither `operator[]` nor `data()` are no-op, both being called inside a loop twice

Answer (score 2):

quick-bench provides an assembly view, so we can look at what the code actually was, instead of guessing how compilers *might* compile the source.

A typical "fast copy" looks something like this:

```
       movdqu (%rcx,%rax,1),%xmm0
66.04% movups %xmm0,(%rsi,%rax,1)
33.96% add    $0x10,%rax
       cmp    $0x100000,%rax
       jne    408c60 <str_loop_ptr(benchmark::State&)+0x110>
```

(this is AT&T syntax, read it the wrong way around)

Don't pay too much attention to the sample frequency in the leftmost column, it's not as if the load and the compare&branch are free, unfortunately we don't really have a sampling mechanism that accurately reflects instruction-level costs. Pipeline simulators (such as [uiCA](https://uica.uops.info/?code=%20%20%20%20movdqu%20(%25rcx,%25rax,1),%25xmm0%0D%0A%20%20%20%20movups%20%25xmm0,(%25rsi,%25rax,1)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add%20%20%20%20$0x10,%25rax%0D%0A%20%20%20%20cmp%20%20%20%20$0x100000,%25rax%0D%0A%20%20%20%20jne%20%20%20%20loop&syntax=asATT&uArchs=SKL&tools=uiCA&alignment=0)) give a better overview of the costs, except when they diverge from reality, which they sometimes do (uiCA is quite good though).

Anyway the code looks good, copying 16 bytes at the time with no unnecessary nonsense.

`str_loop` and `str_loop_data` both look like this:

```
mov    0x20(%rsp),%rdx
movzbl (%rdx,%rax,1),%ecx
mov    (%rsp),%rdx
mov    %cl,(%rdx,%rax,1)
add    $0x1,%rax
cmp    $0x100000,%rax
jne    4086f0 <str_loop(benchmark::State&)+0x100>
```

This time only one byte is copied at the time instead of 16, and both the source and destination pointers are read from the stack every time instead of held in registers. I don't see any good reason why the code *should* be compiled that way (if "maybe the pointer held by the `string` object points to that pointer itself" was an argument, then that argument should also apply to `vector`, but the version with vectors *was* vectorized). But compilers don't always need a *good* reason to do things, they can also just get confused..

That suggests some possible alterations to the code though, we can help the compiler in its analysis by making copies of the pointers before the loop, which is in general a useful technique:

```
  for (auto _ : state) {
    char* dst = a.data();
    char* src = b.data();
    for(size_t i=0;i<N;i++) dst[i]=src[i];
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(a);benchmark::DoNotOptimize(b);
  }
```

With this, [we do get that vectorized loop](https://quick-bench.com/q/EAG9yQtu7zG3P5nS2oo0njeI9Ho) (note that I reduced the number of benchmarks there, so the graph looks a bit different).

Answer (score 2):

when calling `operator[]` or `data()[]`, some compilers are not good at optimizing the code.

```
11.41% movzx  esi,BYTE PTR [rsi+rdx*1]
11.96% mov    BYTE PTR [rdi+rdx*1],sil
14.11% inc    rdx
2.29%  cmp    rdx,0x100000
       je     14710 <str_loop(benchmark::State&)+0xb0>
2.58%  test   BYTE PTR [rsp],0x1
11.20% mov    rsi,rax
12.25% je     14742 <str_loop(benchmark::State&)+0xe2>
2.41%  mov    rsi,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10]
3.25%  test   BYTE PTR [rsp+0x18],0x1
11.06% mov    rdi,rcx
12.34% je     14720 <str_loop(benchmark::State&)+0xc0>
2.24%  mov    rdi,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28]
2.90%  jmp    14720 <str_loop(benchmark::State&)+0xc0>
```

while using pointer, compiler knows that the memory is continuous and it generates much better assembly.

```
0.22%  movups xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1]
4.57%  movups xmm1,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1+0x10]
1.77%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1],xmm0
2.18%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1+0x10],xmm1
0.95%  movups xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1+0x20]
36.92% movups xmm1,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1+0x30]
3.91%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1+0x20],xmm0
3.34%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1+0x30],xmm1
3.18%  movups xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1+0x40]
3.72%  movups xmm1,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1+0x50]
0.63%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1+0x40],xmm0
3.94%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1+0x50],xmm1
1.42%  movups xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1+0x60]
24.56% movups xmm1,XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rdi*1+0x70]
3.22%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1+0x60],xmm0
2.43%  movups XMMWORD PTR [rdx+rdi*1+0x70],xmm1
2.71%  sub    rdi,0xffffffffffffff80
0.25%  cmp    rdi,0x100000
```

Comment: Where did you get the assembly from? What code did you compile to get it, using which compiler? It's not from the quick-bench linked by OP

Comment: The reason might be that for a class type, the overloaded `operator[]` or the member function `data()` (or whatever) can just do anything the writer wants. The compiler cannot assume anything about it so they cannot be optimized recklessly.

Comment: @Fareanor there is no evidence for that here, that first code snippet does not contain a call to an opaque `operator[]` (or `data()`? who knows, since we still don't know what this was compiled from). There is a bunch of other nonsense going on, but not that.

Comment: @harold I was not talking about the assembly code (I doesn't understand assembly tbh) but I reacted about _"when calling `operator[]` or `data()[]`, some compilers are not good at optimizing the code."_

Comment: @harold it was from the OP's link, I got the above assembly code. but I tried GCC and CLANG versions.